# LinQ where clause contains using &&

Tags: linq

```
   var yCols = from t in flowPath
                select new {checkPoint = t["CheckPoint"]};
    var test = from x in operations
               where x["Ops"] = "test" && x["check"].Contains(yCols.Select(y=>y.Variable))
```

Somehow the contains in where clause part is not right.yCols returns Collection of Checkpoints and if x["Check"] contains any of the values then retrieve the value.Whats the best way to do this.

Comment: What is operations? Why are you doing one projection to get yCols and then immediately doing another one? What is this actually meant to *do*?

Comment: What are you expecting, and what is it doing wrong, exactly? For starters, `x["Ops"] = "test"` should be `x["Ops"] == "test"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
].Contains(yCols.Select(y=>y.checkPoint)) .It's not "y.Variable" but "y.checkPoint"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> yCols =
  from t in flowPath 
  select t["CheckPoint"];

IEnumerable<Operation> test =
  from x in operations 
  where x["Ops"] == "test" && yCols.Contains(x["check"])
  select x;
```

- Your code is more clear if you don't use var.
- Use == to compare and = to assign.  Don't use = in where.
- Items don't contain collections.  Collections contain items.